# Some kind of "bijection" between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem is: prove the existence of function $f: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x,y)=f(y,z)\implies x=y=z$.
I was thinking about $f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{iff $x=y$}\\
something & \textrm{ iff $x\neq y$}
\end{array} \right.$
but I guess we need to have bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to do that, which don't exist because $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{R}|$.
EDIT: let's make it clear. If we take some $c \neq g$, $f(c,c)$ can't be equal to $f(g,g)$.

Comment: @pingwindyktator I don't understand how your edit follows from the question. If it does, the question is easy (just count the possible values of $f(a, a)$), but I think showing this is hard.

Comment: Haven't you proven it is impossible? if $x,y \in R; x \ne y$ then $f(x,x) \ne f(y,y)$.  So g(x) = f(x,x) f: R -> N is an injective function.  Which is impossible.  So such a function can't exist?  At least I think so.  I could have made a careless error.

Comment: @fleablood The OP's edit is at odds with their actual question . . .

Comment: @pingwindyktator You still haven't addressed my first comment (which is the important one).

Comment: @NoahSchweber right, Im stupid.

Comment: @fleablood I don't know, my math professor gave me this saying it's possible to find this function. But in the other hand - I think you can be right.

Comment: @pingwindyktator See my answer - they do exist!

Comment: Oops.  my error.  x \ne y so f(x,x) = (y,y) is not a case of (x = $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ = y$).  *VERY* careless error on my part.  f(x,x) = f(y,y) => f(x,z) = f(z,y) iff x = z and z = y which, duh, need not be the case.

Comment: Nope, I'm definitely wrong.  f(x,x) = f(y,y) \=> x = y as .... x and y aren't the same.

Comment: Hate making such careless errors.

Comment: @pingwindyktator I think we now have agreement (except for you) that this statement does not follow from the previous parts of your question: "If we take some $c \neq g$, $f(c,c)$ can't be equal to $f(g,g)$." If you cannot be happy unless it is true, you can _add_ it to the other conditions, but then it changes the question (and presumably makes it a different question from what your instructor asked).

Comment: I don't have a take yet.  I made a stupid error that (x,x)  (y,y) was an example of (x,z) (z,y) which it obviously isn't.  With such a mistake, it was inevitable that f(x,x) is injective which is of course impossible.  But as (x,x) is NOT a case a case of (x,z) (z, y) I'm simply back to square one.  Except that I have the trivial and useless fact that there some x \ne y such that f(x,x) = f(y,y) which I doubt helps us.

Comment: It's kind of a dyslexic error.  (x,y) (y, z) => x=y=z so (x,x)(y,y) is such a case.  Um.... no, it isn't.  (x, !Y!)(!Y!, z)  when !Y! = !Y!  so (x, !X!) (!Y!, y) when !X! = !Y! and .... whoops.  Very, very foolish but *easy* to make.  *sigh*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding: the original condition

$$f(x, y)=f(y, z)\implies x=y=z$$

**does not** imply the new (added in an edit) condition

$$f(x, x)=f(y, y)\implies x=y.$$

To see this, consider the following counterexample: let $f: \{1, 2\}\rightarrow \{1, 2, 3\}$ be given by

- $f(1, 1)=f(2, 2)=1$,
- $f(1,2)=2$, and
- $f(2, 1)=3$.

This $f$ satisfies the original condition, but not the new condition.

It's easy to show that there are no functions $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the new condition. Perhaps surprisingly, if we restrict attention to the original condition, *there are such functions*! Moreover, we don't even need something silly like the axiom of choice to build them!

---

*Construction*. Let $\mathcal{A}=\{A_r: r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be a family of sets **of natural numbers other than $0$** with the property that $$r\not=s\implies A_r\setminus A_s\not=\emptyset.$$

Now define $f(r, s)$ as follows:

- If $r\not=s$, then $f(r, s)$ is the least element of $A_r\setminus A_s$.
- If $r=s$, then $f(r, s)$ is $0$.

---

*Verification*. Now suppose $f(x, y)=f(y, z)$ and it is *not* the case that $x=y=z$.

First, let's see that the numbers $x, y, z$ must be distinct. Suppose $x=y$. Then $f(x, y)=0$. But since $y\not=z$ (by assumption that "$x=y=z$" fails) then $f(y, z)\in A_y\not\ni0$, so $f(y, z)\not=f(x, y)$. Similarly, we can't have $y=z$.

So $x, y, z$ are distinct. But then $f(x, y)\in A_x\setminus A_y$, and $f(y, z)\in A_y\setminus A_z$. In particular, we have

- $f(x, y)\not\in A_y$, but
- $f(y, z)\in A_y$.

**Oops.**

---

*Caveat*. Of course I'm skipping a crucial step here: *showing that such a family $\mathcal{A}$ actually exists.* Since there was some disagreement over whether such families actually exist, let me give a concrete one here:

Fix your favorite bijection $F$ between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of finite binary strings $2^{<\omega}$; separately, fix your favorite bjection $G$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and the set of infinite binary strings $2^\omega$. Now, given a real $r$, we view each real $r$ as an infinite sequence, and let $A_r$ be the set of natural numbers standing for initial segments of that sequence: more formally, we let $$A_r=\{F^{-1}(\sigma): \sigma\prec G(r)\}.$$

The resulting family is in fact an *almost disjoint* family: the intersection $A_r\cap A_s$ for $r\not=s$ is always finite, but every $A_r$ is infinite!

Comment: genius. Thanks!

Comment: @pingwindyktator This is a great example of just how weird sets can be - even at a fairly concrete level! This seemed "obviously false" to me as well, and I spent a while trying to disprove it; after the fifth or so time I failed, I started to see a pattern :P.

Comment: but you didnt get my edit right. "If we take some $c\neq g$, $f(c,c)$ can't be equal to $f(g,g)$" is $c \neq g \implies f(c,c) \neq f(g,g)$ :)

Comment: @pingwindyktator That's the contrapositive of what I wrote - they're equivalent. (Keep in mind $f$ is a function, so if $c=g$ we'll by definition have $f(c, c)=f(g, g)$.)

Comment: Reread your edit:   (x,y)(y, z)  is a case of the second term of the first being the first term of the second.  i.e. (x, W)(Y, z) where W = Y.  That is simply not the case with (x,x)(z,z)  this is a case of (x, W)(Y, z) where W = x $\ne$ z = Y$.   The second term of the first (x) is NOT equal to the first term of the second (y). It simply doesn't follow.  I feel very abashed as I fell for it to... but it was simply an oversight.

Comment: Okay, upvoted.  That family is far from trivial to find.  Although the idea that n in A or n not in A can be a binary bit helps.

Comment: @fleablood There's other examples - for instance, let $A_r$ be the range of some Cauchy sequence converging to $r$. Not almost disjoint, but good enough and arguably more natural. (Annoyingly, I *don't* think we can just use Zorn's lemma here - Zorn easily implies an *uncountable* such family, but it takes some work to get a *size continuum* such family.)