# Decomposition of $\mathbb N$ into mutually disjoint infinite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

$$\mathbb N =\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}\Delta_j $$ where each $\Delta_j$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$  and $\Delta_j\cap \Delta_i=\Phi \ for\ i\neq j.$

Now what I need is a few examples of such decompositions. The only one I can think of now is the collection of the odd numbers and the even numbers. That satisfies it.

Another possibility I was considering was like this ::

$$\Delta_1=2\mathbb N\\ \Delta_2=3\mathbb N \backslash \Delta_1\\ \Delta_3=5\mathbb N\backslash (\Delta_1\cup\Delta_2)\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\so\ \ on.$$ The technique here is for any arbitrary $k$ , $\Delta_k=p\mathbb N\backslash \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}\Delta_i\right)$.  Clearly I can see all these sets are  *mutually disjoint*  and also *infinite*  since **there are infinitely many prime numbers.**

So , are there any other construction of this kind possible $?$ If so please let me know . Also , if there is any fault in my above construction point it out .

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may find this interesting: clearly I can only decompose $\mathbb{N}$ into *countably many* disjoint pieces. However, what if I weaken that requirement from "disjoint" to just "almost disjoint" - that is, I demand that $A\cap B$ be *finite* (not necessarily empty) for distinct $A, B$ in my collection? It turns out this has a huge effect - we can now get an *uncountable* almost disjoint family! See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617178/some-kind-of-bijection-between-mathbb-r-and-mathbb-n.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten $1$ in your decomposition, as it is not a multiple of any prime. Also, odds and evens doesn't satisfy since there are only two sets in that case and you need infinitely many.

Comment: @AdamHughes : So , my decomposition is totally wrong or is there some modification possible to make it work. I'm guessing I could choose $\Delta_1=\{1\}\cup 2\mathbb N.$ That would include $1$ and solve the problem . Right $?$ Or is there still some problem pls notify.

Comment: @user118494 yeah, it's very easy to fix, that was just a minor quibble. Put $1$ into the first one and you're golden.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/partitioning-an-infinite-set adn http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750432/equivalence-relation-on-mathbbn-with-infinitely-many-equivalence-classes

Answer (score 2):

For every $j\ge 1$, let $\Delta_j$ consist of all natural numbers of the form $2^{j-1} m$, where $m$ is odd.

*Remarks*: $1.$ This can be used to produce a simple bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.

$2.$ You can get an interesting example of a different character by using the [Cantor Pairing Function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) Note that the linked article includes $0$ among the natural numbers, so you will have to modify it a little if you want $\mathbb{N}$ to exclude $0$.

Comment: For a $\Delta_j$ , when $j$ is fixed, and $m$ varies over the odd numbers ?

Comment: @user118494: If I understand your comment, then yes. For example $\Delta_3$ consists of the numbers $4,12,20,28,36,44,\dots$.

Comment: You are welcome.